# Predicted Values on Test Sample? (GBM). Worse than a Coinflip

Tags: r, gbm

I am predicting a binary outcome (0,1) using gbm in R. After fitting a gbm model on a training set (using Cross-Validation), I am able to obtain the predicted values for the training set by:

```
p<-predict(gbm_model,type="response")
```

For the training sample, I obtain pretty accurate results (as expected)

```
    a       FALSE TRUE
  FALSE     1000  238
  TRUE       80  410
```

However, when I try to predict out-of-sample, this is what I obtain:

```
       b
a       FALSE TRUE
  FALSE   360  169
  TRUE     62  123
```

Clearly, there appears to be an issue, as my model is performing worse than a coin flip on TRUE occurrences. Thus, I was wondering, is there a way to obtain predicted probabilities for observations in the test sample? I'd like to examine those to figure out why the model appears to perform so poorly.

Furthermore, I want to know if there is a way to modify a cutoff when creating the classification table. Thanks in advance.

******By the way, here's the code I am using to obtain classification table

```
confusion(predict(gbm_model, test_sample, n.trees = 5000) > 0, test_sample$Outcome_Variable > 0)
```

Comment: Out of  curiosity, are you perhaps overfitting your model?

Comment: Don't believe so, I am using five-fold cross validation, shrinkage value of .005. The algorithm stops once the cross-validation error is minimized. From the classification table on the training sample, the accuracy is 80%, so not terribly over-fitting.